# .htaccess rewrite url without www

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

With the following rules, when I type the url `www.mywebsite.com` I'm redirected to `mywebsite.com/www`. Why ?
I need to be redirected to `mywebsite.com`.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mywebsite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Examples:

`www.mywebsite.com` redirect to => `mywebsite.com/www` | needed => `mywebsite.com`

`www.mywebsite.com/folder` redirect to => `mywebsite.com/www/folder` | needed => `mywebsite.com/folder`

Thanks

Comment: Yes sorry, my bad, this is the real code know. I am on a shared server, how can I activate the RewriteLog ?

Comment: You'd have to implore the hosting provider to get it enabled then. On Apache 2.4 it's a logging option though.

Comment: @anubhava It is actually my full .htaccess

Comment: @anubhava The www.mywebsite.com get a 301 error, and then I'm redirected to mywebsite.com/www.
I don't understand why it takes the "www" subdomain to put it after the url.

Comment: @anubhava Without the htaccess, I can navigate with or whitout the www. What I do not want

Comment: That's not the point. Are you seeing `mywebsite.com/www` being added when .htaccess has been renamed?

Comment: @anubhava No of course.

Answer (score 0):

try this workaround

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mywebsite\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(\/\S*)\s
RewriteRule ^ http://mywebsite.com/%1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Does not seems to do anything :/ . I can access to the site with www and without www. What does the {THE_REQUEST} line does ?

Comment: @Lunic `GET /index.html HTTP/1.1` [RTM](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond). This Cond takes `/index.html`. If `\s` not supported then try `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ (\/[^\ ]*)`